# Trying to create a formula for showing a flag on a field but my forumla keeps showing Error: Syntax error. Missing ')'

Tags: formula-field, image-formula

I am trying to create a formula, this is the on I am working on.

The first IF statement is working OK but the other two are not. The logic required is;

Additional Formula : Existing formula + Yellow Flag: 1 Working day before the Target Date

Red Flag: When the target date is reached

Please help!

```
IF(Preferred_Locate_Date__c <= TODAY(),
IMAGE("/img/samples/flag_red.gif", "red"), 
IF (DATEVALUE()Target_Date__c) <= TODAY()),
IMAGE("/img/samples/flag_red.gif", "red"),
IF (DATEVALUE()Target_Date__c)= TODAY()+1),
IMAGE("/img/samples/flag_yellow.gif", "yellow"), ""))
```

Comment: `DATEVALUE()Target_Date__c` should be `DATEVALUE(Target_Date__c)`

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].  Pro tip - when building formulas, it's best to use text editor with brace/bracket highlighting (Notepad++, Sublime Text, etc) so you can quickly see where you have too many or too few parentheses.

Answer (score 2):

Lets start with basic of [IF function](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_if.htm&type=5):

`IF(logical_test, value_if_true, value_if_false)`

Nested IF can be written as:

```
IF(logicalCondition1, 
    "value 1", 
    IF(logicalCondition2,
        "value 2",
        "value 3"
    )
)
```

There are few errors in your formula:

1. `DATEVALUE()Target_Date__c` should be `DATEVALUE(Target_Date__c)`, but in this case you are comparing against date, `DATEVALUE` might not be needed here? If it is required, you can add it as `DATEVALUE(Target_Date__c)`.
2. Extra round brackets: this can easily solved with treating formulas like you would do code or whichever formatting make sense to you. Important is to have a good structure for [intendation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style), as it makes complex formulas better readable.

Using the above principle and structure, your formula can be re-written as:

```
IF(
    Preferred_Locate_Date__c <= TODAY(), 
    IMAGE("/img/samples/flag_red.gif", "red"),
    IF(
        Target_Date__c <= TODAY(),
        IMAGE("/img/samples/flag_red.gif", "red"),
        IF(
            Target_Date__c= TODAY()+1,
            IMAGE("/img/samples/flag_yellow.gif", "yellow"),
            "")
    )
)
```

The logic might still not be 100% correct and you may need to adjust it as per your requirement. But above edited formula should be able to compile. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks so much Raul that has worked perfectly!